# Set picker view to value on load

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` to have my picker start up on a certain value. For example if I had a picker that shows :
1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5
can i have it start up on 3. Does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: And where's the question about Xcode? I don't see it.

Comment: The code is being used in xcode that is why I said Xcode.

Comment: Well, the problem and the solution would be indifferent if you used another IDE - it's not related to Xcode.

Comment: Okay sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this instance method:

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

[UIPickerView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

In your case it will be something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myPickerView selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}
```